# Is there any way to change definition of default user created for scratch org without using custom sfdx plugin?

Tags: salesforcedx, user, debugging, user-management, debug

Is there any way to change definition of default user created for scratch org?

I would like the default Administrator user to have properties

`UserPreferencesUserDebugModePref`
`UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode`

set to true.

I know that I could create a config file `adminUser.json` with content

```
{"UserPreferencesUserDebugModePref":true,
"UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode":true,
"ProfileName":"System Administrator",
"LastName":"Debug Mode Admin"}
```

and I could execute two commands

```
call sfdx force:org:create -s -d 30 -f config/DE.json -a ScratchOrg
call sfdx force:user:create -f config/adminUser.json -a DebugModeAdmin
```

but I don't want two users to be created but rather I would like the default user created by `force:org:create` command to have debug mode set. Is this possible? How can this be achieved?

Comment: I have found a way to resolve this without using custom sfdx plugin.

It is possible to grab the `user Id` using `jq` library and then use `record update` command with `-i` switch flag to update the auto-generated user like following

    sfdx force:data:record:update -s User -i $(sfdx force:user:display --json | jq '.result.id' -r)   -v "LanguageLocaleKey=en_US"

Answer (score 0):

You can use data
update command from CLI to update the User record after Scratch Org creation. Refer here for documentation on SFDX data commands: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm

Refer this thread which does it with a cli plugin so that name/id field doesn't has to be hard-coded. [How to customize the auto-generated user of a DX scratch org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236506/how-to-customize-the-auto-generated-user-of-a-dx-scratch-org)